# How to change Eclipse autocomplete priorities for overloaded methods?

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete, overloading

I'm using the log4j2 library for Logging. There are several overloads for the logging methods like `Logger.error(...)`. If i now type `myLogger.error` my prefered option is located pretty far down inside the list which is okay:
[image: Eclipse Autocompletion]
But if I now open the parenthesis `myLogger.error(` eclipse is using autofill for the arguments for the first method:
[image]
Which is annoying, since I have to remove the unnecessary arguments each time.

I don't want to disable autofill in general. I just want to blacklist some specific methods, or set a priority for the autocompletion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was also trying to do exactly what you wanted. I've found that in `Preferences → Java → Editor → Content Assist` there is a option "Type Filters" that you can use.

But my real solution was to create a template. In `Java → Editor → Content Assist → Templates` I've put one template for each debug level:

So "log.d" would become

```
debug("${cursor}", ${var});
```

I have to click Ctrl-Space twice to get it, but it is working well.

Comment: The type filters worked for me, but I could not make the template method work. Perhaps a more detailed explanation would help.